# space of $\omega$-tame almost complex structures and $\mathrm{Diff}(M)$

Tags: reference-request, sg.symplectic-geometry, symplectic-topology

Let $(M,\omega)$ be a symplectic manifold, and $J$ is an almost complex structure on $M$. $J$ is said to be **$\omega$-tame** if
$$
\omega(v, Jv) >0
$$
for all non-zero $v\in TM$.

It is commonly said that the space $J_{tame}(M,\omega)$ of $\omega$-tame almost complex structure is 'open'. Naively, the tameness condition above is a strict inequality, and thus it is an 'open' condition: a small perturbation of $J$ will not change it. However, my understand is pretty vague.

I was wondering if the topology we used here comes from the topology in $\mathrm{Diff}(M)$. In particular, I have the following question:

**Question**: Given an $\omega$-tame almost complex structure $J$, does there exist a neighborhood $\mathcal U$ of the identity $\mathrm{Id}$ in $\mathrm{Diff}(M)$ such that for any $\phi\in \mathcal U$ we have $d\phi \circ J \circ d\phi^{-1} \in \mathcal J_{tame}(M,\omega)$ is still $\omega$-tame?

**Question 2**:  Let $\mathcal U$ be a small neighborhood of $Id$ in $\mathrm{Diff}(M)$ as above, then we have two metrics $g_J=\omega(\cdot, J\cdot)$ and $g_{J^\phi}=\omega(\cdot, J^\phi\cdot)$ where$J^\phi=d\phi \circ J \circ d\phi^{-1}$. Does there exist a constant $C > 1$ so that
$$
\frac{1}{C} g_J\le g_{J^\phi} \le C g_J, 
$$
for any $\phi\in \mathcal U$?

Comment: I suggest you have a look at a standard book on differential topology that treats topologies for various spaces of functions or more generally sections of bundles. For instance, Hirsch's book, Differential Topology,  explains the $C^k$ and $C^\infty$ topologies; these should be sufficient. (It's moderately fussy if M is not compact.) Once you have the right topology, the proof of openness should be straightforward.

Comment: See Wendl's lecture notes *"Lectures on Holomorphic Curves in
Symplectic and Contact Geometry"*, chapter 2 (and then look pointwise to understand that the strict inequality is an open condition).